# Register Errors and device drivers

Tags: driver

I am writing a device driver where I need to read and write to a lot of registers.  Is there any way I can tell if the operation as been successful? Currently we have a driver for some old HW but all of the driver functions are void and we just assume the operation was successful.

Are there any known tips or design patterns which would be good to follow when making a device driver?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You could do any of the following which suits you :

1) just write the register and immediately read back the same register.
2) create a function which outputs the value of each register when called.

Just make sure some registers might reset when read from it ( This might cause your code to malfunction )